# Open pygame fullscreen window in secondary monitor

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to build a simple game to be projected onto a table to do a small AR demo.

To do this, I need to open the game window in fullscreen mode on a second monitor (projector). I have seen in other questions asked here that there is no way to do this directly in pygame.
Can anyone suggest me another way to open a pygame window on a separate display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem by using SDL environment variables before initializing pygame:

```
x = 0
y = 0
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = f"{x},{y}"
```

By specifying x, the left border of the window will open in that location.

e.g. If you have two monitors with resolution 1920*1080 and x=0, the window will open in the left monitor; if x=1920 it will opened in the right monitor.

Since I also want the window to be fullcreen without a border I specify the flag NOFRAME in set_mode:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), flags = pygame.NOFRAME)
```

Comment: ... and if the monitors are swapped then `x = -1920` (or whatever is the appropriate number for the monitor) does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

No way to `test(now)` if that solves exactly your problem, but
display has

```py
set_mode(size=(0, 0), flags=0, depth=0, display=0)
```

which features display argument

Comment: Your sollution should have worked but the window still comes up in the primary display. I've tried connecting and disconecting a second monitor but pygame.display.get_num_displays always returns 1. In the docs it says "This is always 1 if pygame.get_sdl_version()get the version number of SDL returns a major version number below 2." and mine returns V1.2.15 so I guess this is my problem. Do you know if there is a way to update the sdl version used by pygame? I saw that there is a pygame_sdl2 repo but it seems a bit experimental yet.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Just remembered there was function like that, but haven't used pygame for a long time.